# Inequality for open set measures

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

How do you prove that, given a sequence of open sets $I_i$ (in $\mathbb{R}^n)$, it is possible, given $\varepsilon>0$, to find a s sequence of open sets $J_i$ such that $I_i \subset J_i$ (strict inclusion) and $\sum
|J_i| \leqslant \sum |I_i| + \varepsilon$ ? Here $|A|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $A$.

Comment: Let $J_i = I_i$.

Comment: For strict inclusion, add one new point to each $I_i$.

Comment: Before your edit, $J_i$ did not have to be open. If you want it to be open, for each $I_i$, pick any $x \notin I_i$. Let $B_i$ be any ball centered at $x$ with measure less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}$. Let $J_i = I_i \cup B_i$. $J_i$ is a strict superset since it contains $x$. It is clear that the $|J_i| \leq |I_i| + \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $I_i$, pick any $x \notin I_i$. Let $B_i$ be any ball centered at $x$ with measure less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}$. Let $J_i = I_i \cup B_i$. $J_i$ is a strict superset since it contains $x$. It is clear that the $|J_i| \leq |I_i| + \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$.